# How to aggregate events from multiple calendars to master calendar?

Tags: calendar, aggregation

Across a site collection, various sites maintain their own calendars.  Meanwhile, users have requested that events for those subgroups be aggregated and displayed on a master calendar.

Question: Out-of-the-box (OOB), how can I aggregate calendar events from multiple calendars onto a master calendar?

Think departments within a division; each department with its own SharePoint site with its own calendar, and division with its master calendar used to show selected aggregated events from the departments.  Some department events may not be suitable for displaying on the division calendar.  How do I do this in SharePoint OOB?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In 2010 calendars have a built-in "Calendars Overlay" function under the Calendar tab. This allows you to display information from other calendars on the current view.

Bjørn Furuknap has an article on the subject here: [View Multiple Calendars in SharePoint 2010](http://blog.furuknap.net/view-multiple-calendars-in-sharepoint-2010)

Answer (score 3):

There is a great article with step by step instructions that explains how to aggregate several calendars from different data sources, including SharePoint, in master SharePoint calendar: [How to aggregate various Calendars from different data sources into a single SharePoint Calendar?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1023777/aggregate-sharepoint-calendars-from-various-source)

Shortly SharePoint OOTB Calendars have overlay option that allows you to overlay several calendars from department calendars in your master devision calendar. You can define color of the events for each Calendar you want to add. In this case you'll have one calendar that will include all calendars of your departments in one view.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 2):

The Data View Web Part (DVWP) will let you roll up all items across the Site Collection based on whatever criteria you define.  It can be totally dynamic (not sure why Simon feels you need to keep it updated manually).  The trick is the actual view. The Calendar view is a very complex view, and you won't be able to recreate it (at least I haven't ever been able to).  If you're OK with a list of events, then the DVWP is a great solution.

Comment: I am obviously showing my lack of experience with the DVWP ;)

You could do a bit of a joining of solution using the DVWP to dynamically rollup the items across the site collection and then expose that using the Bamboo Calendar web part...

Comment: Am I wrong in thinking that the DVWP allows you to aggregate content from sites within one site collection but I dont think it allows you to aggregate across site collections.

Comment: Right. Probably not the clearest typing on my part. By "across the Site Collection", I meant across *one* Site Collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is another web part that might buy yourself something.  Take a look at the Content Query Web Part.  This will roll up nicely based on the calendars, lists etc that are in a site collection.  The only issue is that I doubt you could recreate the calendar vire you are after.  You would use the Data View Web Part if you were trying to rollup a calendar that is part of another collection.  I believe you indicate you are working in the same collection.

We use a third part web part from coras works that gives you the look and feel of a calendar which is nice because it get us closer to the core requirment rather than seeing the events in list view.  However the layout needs work. \

Paul

Comment: as far as I remember CQWP is only available in SP2010 Std (no foundation support). please correct me if I wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar though struggled to do it in a way that was easily extendable. Though I am sure if you don't mind having to keep it updated then you could use the Data View Web Part to get your raw data.

However the calendar bit is more tricky and I ended up using two products from Bamboo Solutions the List Data Rollup Web Part and Calendar Web Part. It had some nice features for colour coding the department entries and also you can add a list of Holidays on there as well.

To ensure that only certain events rollup use a custom flag on the department calendar called something like GlobalEvent and only roll up the items with this flag set to true.

One of the requirements included a feature where all entries which are displayed on the Global Calendar have to go through an approval process, for this I wrote a custom workflow which set the hidden GlobalEvent flag to true.

Happy to chat about this more.

Regards
Simon

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote an article about syncing any list using a simple workflow. As a Calendar is just a list it works for that as well and it maintains the Calendar look and feel.

[Check it out here](http://www.muhimbi.com/blog/2009/12/automatically-synchronise-sharepoint.html), it works great and deals with attachments as well. As it is part of a workflow you can add your own logic easily, e.g. Only sync calendar events that have field 'x' set to 'y'.

Please note that I worked on this product so am obviously biased.